# How do I loop through arrays and join them together in php?

Tags: php, xml, arrays, csv

I have a small php script that takes product xml values and writes them to a csv file, but I'm having trouble with the product options.
I've extracted options for each product from the xml and added the values to arrays like this.

color[1] color[2] color[3]

size[1] size[2] size[3]

Now I need to make the csv which will look like this;

color[1],size[1]

color[1],size[2]

color[1],size[3]

color[2],size[1]

color[2],size[2]

and so on......

Below is the code I've used to get the info. into the arrays, I'm not even sure this is the best way to do this but it does seem to work ok.

```
        $i=0;
foreach($_item->options->Color as $_color){
        $color[$i] = $_color;
        $i++;
        }
        print $sku;
    foreach($color as $i=>$value){
        print ' - $color[' . $i . '] holds ' . $value;
        }
echo '<br>';

        $i=0;
foreach($_item->options->Size as $_size){
        $size[$i] = $_size;
        $i++;
        }
        print $sku;
    foreach($size as $i=>$value){
        print ' - $size[' . $i . '] holds ' . $value;
        }
echo '<br>';
```

At the moment I'm just printing out the product $sku and the value of the options.
I'd love some pointers on how to get the $color[] and $size[] looped through to get all the possible combinations and write them to the csv.
Thanks

Comment: Are you after nested loops? Iterate over colours; for each colour, iterate over sizes. You'll find `fputcsv()` useful for creating the CSV itself.

Comment: @George-Brighton Thanks for your help, I was actually using fwrite() to make the csv so I'll definitely have a look at fputcsv()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$colors = array("color1", "color2", "color3");

$sizes  = array("size1", "size2", "size3");

$result = array();
foreach($colors as $cKey => $c) {
    foreach($sizes as $s) {
        $result[][$c] = $s;
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
    array (size=9)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'color1' => string 'size1' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'color1' => string 'size2' (length=5)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'color1' => string 'size3' (length=5)
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      'color2' => string 'size1' (length=5)
  4 => 
    array (size=1)
      'color2' => string 'size2' (length=5)
  5 => 
    array (size=1)
      'color2' => string 'size3' (length=5)
  6 => 
    array (size=1)
      'color3' => string 'size1' (length=5)
  7 => 
    array (size=1)
      'color3' => string 'size2' (length=5)
  8 => 
    array (size=1)
      'color3' => string 'size3' (length=5)
```

Comment: Many thanks, works fine. I actually messed about a bit and instead of storing the results in an array, I just looped over the color and size and directly wrote it to the file. Might not be the prettiest solution but it seems to wotk ok.